# How to find tens/ones digit of two different numbers regardless of their length

Tags: python, mathematical-expressions

sorry if this is the wrong place for this question or anything. I picked up a book on python and I'm trying to learn the basics by myself right now. My question is, **if I'm given two different numbers, is there a way I can find the tens and ones digit of both numbers, regardless of the length of each number?** How would I go about doing this? I'm trying to use floor division and modulo because that makes sense but I can't get it quite right. In the future, how should I approach things like this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have tagged this question with `Java`, but it doesn't seem to be related to `Java`. If it isn't, please [edit] your question to remove the java tag, and if it is please edit to explain how this is related to java

Comment: Can you edit the post and include your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Modulo and floor division is probably the best way to go for large numbers:

```
num = 1327419832467138974619485762453

# Tens
print(num % 100 // 10)

# Ones
print(num % 10)
```

Output:

```
5
3
```